# Как правильно ответить на предписание?

Tags: стилистика, канцеляризмы

Здравствуйте.

"Дело в том, что от контролирующих организаций наше предприятие получает предписания, которые состоят из пунктов предписания - замечаний, после выполнения (устранения) которых нам следует дать об этом ответ в письменной форме".

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно дать ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Сложно дать конкретные рекомендации,  не зная ни сути ответа, ни кому предназначено письмо. Почитайте здесь, там неплохие рекомендации, клише и даже образцы. [Как написать деловое письмо](http://artnek.org.ru/?p=850). Может, поможет.  А я бы обратилась к коллегам (какая-то похожая организация есть рядом?) и попросила посмотреть, как они оформляют подобные ответы.

Answer (score 1):

Объясните проблему. Вам рыба нужна? Шаблон в смысле? Пишите в свободной форме, не ошибётесь.

Пока единственное, что могу посоветовать, так это сначала устранить и выполнить - а потом уже отвечать. Главное - перечислить все, что выполнено.